# NDK JNI missing libraries

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run an old android project with JNI. As I am building it in NDK, it keeps on looking for libraries. I checked on the Android.mk file and found these:

> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog -lutils -lui -lbinder
>   -lsurfaceflinger -lcutils 
>   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
>     liblog \
>     libnativehelper \
>     libandroid_runtime \
>     libutils \
>     libui \
>     libbinder \
>     libsurfaceflinger \
>     libcutils

I'm having trouble finding downloads of these libraries, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `adb pull /system/lib` to extract these shared libraries (or all system shared libraries) from your device or emulator.

I believe that `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` is not necessary in your situation. Note that NDK r9 shows a warning about using libraries that are not part of NDK, but it's just a warning.

Comment: am I supposed to specify "adb pull /system/lib" in cygwin? tried it there and got an error. sorry I'm a total newbie with ndk

Comment: More specifically, I got a "device not found" error. I executed this in C:\Android. The contents of this folder are android-ndk, eclipse and sdk folders. Thanks for the help, btw, I'm not supposed to edit the code, just make it run in the eclipse emulator. Eclipse version I have is ADT Juno

Comment: You should start the emulator before you run adb.

Comment: With ADT Eclipse, you may find the [file explorer view](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#views_fileexplorer) useful.